# Object Not Looking at Other Object at Right Angle in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, blender

I'm working on a prototype of a *tower defense game* and I've encountered a problem with the rotation of a turret. I made it so that every turret must have a **rotator** part which rotates *horizontally* and holds the main **turret body** with the **cannon** which rotates *vertically*. I came up with a simple script to this but it only seems to work for the **rotator** and not for the **cannon**, at least not the way it should.

Here is the *code* from the script:

```
void Update () {
    if (target != null) {

        Vector3 tempRotatorRotation = rotator.transform.localEulerAngles;
        rotator.transform.LookAt (target.transform);
        rotator.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3 (tempRotatorRotation.x, rotator.transform.localEulerAngles.y, tempRotatorRotation.z);

        Vector3 tempCannonRotation = cannon.transform.localEulerAngles;
        cannon.transform.LookAt (target.transform);
        cannon.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3 (cannon.transform.localEulerAngles.x, tempCannonRotation.y, tempCannonRotation.z);
    }
}
```

And here is an image of how this turns out. The **rotator** is rotated perfectly, but as you can see the **cannon** is looking down for some reason.
**(Blue is the pedestal which doesn't move. Green is rotator. Red is turret body. Light blue is cannon)**
[image]

The origin of the **cannon** *3D model* is set almost at the start of it.
[image]
Here is the screenshot of the canon selected showing it's axis and transform data
[image]

Comment: There isn't enough information in the question to correctly answer it. It should be put on hold until more information is provided.

Comment: That is literally all the information that is. What else do you need?

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the cannon axes in unity.

Answer (score 1):

`forward` to unity is the blue line, which in your diagram is facing up. try this

crate empty, attach to turret so it rotates, make sure blue line(z axis) is facing your forward direction, you can do this manualy by rotating. then place your barrel as a child of that object, and point that object at target.

ive had to do this several times with blender models, since blender uses the z axis as its vertical axis not its depth axis like unity.

```
-turret_test
    -turret_test_pedestal
    -turret_test_rotater
          -turret_test_turret
               -AIM(new empty, orient the proper direction then add child)
                       -turret_test_cannon
```

Comment: Read my comments on answer by Foggzie. This is not a problem Unity knows that most people use Blender for Unity so it compensates for the difference in the axis

Comment: @veran fors really? Cuz mine doesn't what kind of model are you using fbx? And for that matter the thing is just a cylinder why not just use the in built unity cylinder and remap ur material and save the trouble.lol

Comment: It turns the object but doesn't change the axis labels. Which actually dissorients it more...

Answer (score 0):

Your cannon's barrel points in its `forward` direction, so all you need to use is `cannon.transform.LookAt (target.transform, cannon.transform.up);`

```
void Update () {
    if (target != null) {

        /* rotator code here */

        // Remember which way the top of the cannon faces.
        Vector3 cannonUpDirection = cannon.transform.up;

        // point the cannon directly at the target
        cannon.transform.LookAt (target.transform, cannonUpDirection);
    }
}
```

If the rotator isn't pointing at/above/below the target, then you have to figure out how much to rotate the canon upwards/downwards from the horizontal, then point it in the same direction as the rotator and then do that:

```
void Update () {
    if (target != null) {

        /* rotator code here */

        // Remember which way the top of the cannon faces.
        Vector3 cannonUpDirection = cannon.transform.up;

        // point the cannon directly at the target
        cannon.transform.LookAt (target.transform, cannonUpDirection);

        // Find global direction for looking straight ahead above/below the target
        Vector3 sameYDirection  = Vector3.Scale(
                cannon.transform.forward, 
                new Vector3(1f,0f,1f)
                );

        // Convert that to local
        Vector3 sameYDirectionLocal = cannon.transform
                .InverseTransformDirection(sameYDirection);  

        // get rotation for moving from looking ahead to looking direct
        Quaternion lookTowards = Quaternion.FromToRotation(
                sameYDirectionLocal, 
                Vector3.forward
                );

        // lookTowards is a locally-vertical rotation from horizontal to the target, 
        // given some top side of the cannon. 
        // Clamp lookTowards here if you have a max rotation speed.

        // Face cannon in same direction of rotator;
        cannon.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(
                rotator.forward, cannonUpDirection);

        // Use lookTowards to look down from that position.
        cannon.transform.rotation *= lookTowards;
    }
}
```

Comment: This somehow made it worse. The part of the code you removed is there to make the equation more precise and not change the rotation of the canon in some other way. Maybe it has a Z rotation too that mustn't change so it must remember it somehow. I obviously need to add or change something to the equation, not remove.

Comment: Please be more descriptive than "made it worse".

Comment: it went from being off by ~50 degrees to ~90

Comment: Basically instead of looking down at the Z+ axis it is looking down at the Z- axis

Comment: Instead of correctly looking along the Z+ axis, it's looking 180º in the opposite direction along the Z- axis? Is there other code changing the rotation of the cannon or its parent objects? It may be getting modified further between renders. If it's 180º off, it's possible that the cannon is pointing `back` instead of `forward`. A screenshot of the cannon's axes in Unity after this code runs would make things a lot clearer.

Comment: `cea.x`is supposed to be the same as `cannon.transform.eulerAngles.x`, so I don't understand the problem with that. The intent is to keep the `x` and `z` euler components to be based on the result of `lookAt` and the `y` component based on `rotator`. Good luck getting the help you need with the way you treat volunteer help.

Comment: ohhhh... the y is from the rotator? My bad... I thought it was cannon.transform.eulerAngles.y.... In that case... It still didn't work!

Comment: @VeranFors I edited my question to handle locking to the rotator differently, as well as included code to keeping the cannon rotated around its `z` axis consistently.

Answer (score -2):

Turns out Unity is broken and when I re-imported the model all the axis have changed and instead of the canon turning in the X axis up and down now it was in the Y axis while everything else rotates horizontally in Y.

Also in the calculation I had to add + 90 to both equations. This will make no sense now since it shows both are changing in Y axis but one is rotating horizontally and the other vertically.

```
if (target != null) {

    Vector3 tempRotatorRotation = rotator.transform.localEulerAngles;
    rotator.transform.LookAt (target.transform);
    rotator.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3 (tempRotatorRotation.x, rotator.transform.localEulerAngles.y + 90, tempRotatorRotation.z);

    Vector3 tempCanonRotation = canon.transform.localEulerAngles;
    canon.transform.LookAt (target.transform);
    canon.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3 (tempCanonRotation.x, canon.transform.localEulerAngles.y + 90, tempCanonRotation.z);
}
```

Comment: You should use `transform.Rotate` instead of adding to localEulerAngles. This won't work properly if it exceeds 360.